# Building in the new Xcode

Tags: xcode

I just upgraded to the new Xcode a few days ago, and wow has everything changed. I think I've been able to get used to everything, except one thing. How do I do build for certain profiles? Whereas before each profile had its own settings, it seems that the settings are combined in this version. For example, I want one profile with an entitlements.plist file, and I want another profile without it, but it seems now I can only have one way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for schemes. You can find those settings in the listbox next to run & stop (on the toolbar). New/Edit Scheme should allow you to add remove things depending on the selected build.